# dnrgps converting images to waypoints

Tags: gps, photos

Help! I am downloading waypoints collected with our Garmin Montana 680t Software version 280. That works fine. Get a table of waypoints collected. The user also took photos which are geotagged with the waypoints. In order to link the photos with the waypoints, I need to convert images to waypoints in the [DNRGPS](http://www.dnr.state.mn.us/mis/gis/DNRGPS/DNRGPS.html) software using Edit> Add Image Links. When I go through this process, the identifier field is replaced with the name of the photo starting with the default DSC00000. The comment field disappears altogether and this is the information I need for what was at that location (another identifier). So I have to export 2 different files to shapefiles to use in ArcMap. Does anyone out there have any idea why this happens and what I can do to rectify?

Comment: What do you call "convert image to waypoint"? An image is a matrix of pixel values. Waypoints are points. You may have a bug in your processing software. Have you tried other software to manipulate image metadata in a proper way?